# Symfony2 - Best Practices to trigger 404 exception

Tags: php, symfony, exception, model-view-controller, entity

what is a best practice to throw Exceptions in Symfony?

There is a good example in documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#managing-errors-and-404-pages to throw exception in Controller.

Second way is throw Exception in Model, for example I have Entity Product with this method:

```
class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getProductBySlug($slug)
    {
        $product = $this->findOneBySlug($slug);
        if (is_null($product )) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('Unable to find product : "%s".!', $slug));
        }
        return $product ;
    }
}
```

If I will call getProductBySlug many times, I will not duplicate exception code. What is better way?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put your exceptions in methods that are called by your controller, and use those methods in every controller so you don't have to duplicate the code.

You can :

- create Services which uses the Entity Repository and handle the
  Exceptions in it (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)
- put Exceptions in your Repository like you did in your example

The first case provides a cleaner code but add a little more complexity, the second case is faster to implement.

Answer (score 2):

my common practice is your code a some bit shorter

```
    public function getProductBySlug($slug)
    {
        $product = $this->findOneBySlug($slug);
        if (!$product) {
            return $this->createNotFoundException("This does not exist");
        }
        return $product ;
    }
```

http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html

Answer (score 2):

Throw an HttpException in a service/repository is a bad idea. If you need this service in a command or must outsource them in a other example, you have bad cards.

The best solution is throw a (custom) exception in your services and repositories or sometimes return null or a null object. Then the controller can throw an HttpException which triggers an 404 page or forward to an another page.

Convert a NotFoundException to a 404 page is the default behaviour, but this can be changed.

Clean code should always be your goal, then you have less problems if your code grown up or your requirements has been changed. Write 2 lines of code more takes 2s, but maintain bad code can take hours.

Answer (score 1):

What you currently have is fine IMO. One suggestion that I currently implement is an exception helper that controllers access to throw exceptions. You can also implement try/catch within the helper to keep your code nice a clean in the event that you do not want to throw.

The purpose of this is to keep all your strings, logging and what not in the same location for easy updating. An example being what if you were to update how you log your exceptions? If its in a helper then its a simple change.